# Combination of Flipable and MouseArea going wrong in qml

Tags: qt, qml

It might be possible this is a bug, but please read on:

in the following code, the mousearea on the front of the flipable stays active when the flipable flips (but reversed), and even takes over some mousearea from the back side:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    height: 500
    width: 500

    Flipable {
        id: flipable

        anchors.fill:parent

        property bool flipped: false

        front: Rectangle{
            color: "black"
            anchors.fill: parent

            Rectangle {
                color:"darkgrey"
                height: parent.height / 2
                width: parent.width / 2

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: flipable.flip()
                }
            }
        }
        back: Rectangle {
            id: yellow
            color: "yellow"
            anchors.fill: parent

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: yellow.color = "green"
            }
        }

        transform: Rotation {
            id: rotation
            origin.x: flipable.width/2
            origin.y: flipable.height/2
            axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0     // set axis.y to 1 to rotate around y-axis
            angle: 0    // the default angle
        }

        states: State {
            name: "back"
            PropertyChanges { target: rotation; angle: 180 }
            when: flipable.flipped
        }

        transitions: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { target: rotation; property: "angle"; duration: 400 }
        }

        function flip () {
            flipped = !flipped
        }
    }
}
```

The page flips when you press the grey area, and if it is pressed again (now it is behind the right side) it flips again. The correct behaviour would be that the yellow square becomes green, even when clicking in the upper right corner.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add an explicit question to the... question.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling front and back elements alternatively solved this problem for me:

```
front: Rectangle {
    enabled: !parent.flipped
    ...
}

back: Rectangle {
    enabled: parent.flipped
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting the solution! Spent like 5 hours trying to solve this exact problem... Now i feel like a tard. :P

Answer (score 1):

> The correct behaviour would be that the yellow square becomes green,
>   even when clicking in the upper right corner.

I commented this line :

```
preventStealing: true // doesnt work with my QtQuick 1.0
```

and it is behaving the correct way.

Why had you put it in the first place ?

Comment: nope, still doesn't work

can you copy your code? maybe you added something?

I edited the above so it's without the preventStealing (same result).